# Why does this output "7 9 35 5 27" and not "7 35 5 9 27"?

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        int y = 7;
        System.out.print(m(x, y) + " " + x + " " + m(y, x));
    }

    public static int m(int x, int y) {
        x += 2;
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        y -= 2;
        return (x * y);
    }
```

I tried writing this down on paper and going through the steps. In the first method call, x has 2 added to it and becomes 7, then is printed. Y is subtracted by 2, becoming 5. Then `x*y` gets returned, which is `7*5 = 35`. So I expect 7 35 for now. Then x is printed, so print a 5. Then in the second method call, 2 is added to x again making it 9. 2 is subtracted from y, making 3. Then `x*y` is returned, outputting 27.

So in the end, I expect 7 35 5 9 27.

Comment: "So I expect 7 35 for now. " I don't understand. Why do you think the 35 should be printed at this point? "Then x is printed, so print a 5." I don't understand. Why do you think this print should happen before the second method call?

Comment: No, `x` & `y` isn't returned. You return a *value* of their multiplication, which you never use anyway. Java also doesn't have any syntax to pass value by reference, so unless you explicitly return them (perhaps as part of a custom class) and assign them back to the caller, `x` and `y` shouldn't change

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I think OP understands that `x` and `y` are not passed by reference. If they weren't, they would have expected the second `m` call to also return 35.

Comment: @Sweeper They do expect that since they say in the second call `x` would be 9

Comment: @Martheen note that `y` is passed in the position of `x` there, so it starts off as 7 and then as 2 added to it

Comment: @harold, Yes, I know that, but OP says "Then in the second method call, 2 is added to x again making it 9. 2 is subtracted from y, making 3", the misunderstanding is theirs

Comment: @Martheen but `x = 7, y = 5` (inside the second call to `m`) at that point (not because they were modified, they weren't, but they were passed "in reverse"), so that math is correct.

Comment: @harold The end result is identical, but the *steps* there aren't. OP assumed x is incremented by 2 twice and y decremented by 2 twice. OP didn't write the code and likely assumed parameter order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Martheen maybe? I don't see any strong evidence for that. The word "again" maybe hints at that, but could also mean that `x += 2;` is executed for the second time. It's fairly ambiguous with the multiple meanings of `x` and `y` which OP does not clearly distinguish. The only misunderstanding I actually see is that OP thinks the outer `print` prints some parts of its argument before it has been fully evaluated - and that by itself already fully explains OPs expected result.

Answer (score 4):

> So I expect 7 35 for now

That doesn't make sense. Unless you think that java will print each element in `m(x, y) + " " + x + " " + m(y, x)` 'on the fly'.

That isn't how it works.

The compiler first treats this statement as:

- Invoke `m`, passing 'x' and 'y'. This prints `7` , and resolves to 35.
- resolve the binary operator of _string concat (A,B) where A is the result of the previous bullet (35) and B is `" "`. It doesn't get printed. Why would it be? We're just working on figuring out what `m(x, y) + " "` is, we haven't at all gotten to the idea that this is passed to `System.out.print` yet.
- This resolves to `35` .
- Next we resolve CONCAT(A, B) where A is that (`35` ) and B is `x`, which resolves to 5. local variables and parameters are unique to each method, the fact that `m` changes `x` is just changing its own copy of x, not `main`'s copy of it, so `x` is still 5. The string we are building up is now `35 5`. This still isn't printed for the same reason.
- Next we resolve CONCAT(A, B) where A is that (`35 5`) and B is  , giving us `35 5` .
- Next we resolve CONCAT(A, B) where A is that (`35 5` ) and B is `m(y, x)`. To do that we have to invoke m first to know what that really is, so we do that.
- In passing this prints `9` (remember how every method gets its own unique copy? you called m with `(y, x)`, but the first argument is known as `x` in m, so, it's 7 when called, gets incremented to 9, is printed, and is then multiplied by 3 and returned: 27. So far we've printed `7 9`  as part of `m` calls.
- Finally we can resolve CONCAT(`35 5` , `27`) which gets us `35 5 27`. Which is passed to `System.out.print`. Which prints it.

Thus: 7 9 35 5 27.